# Best practices for LaTeX code in org-mode-beamer (especially url links)

Tags: beamer, emacs, urls, org-mode

I'm using org-mode to produce beamer presentations. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way of including Latex snippets.  As far as I can tell, there are two ways of signalling to org-mode to interpret text as LaTeX code.

The first is to sandwich the LaTeX code between:

```
#+begin_latex
.....[LateX code here]....
#+end_latex
```

The other is to have the line start with `#+LaTeX`:

```
#+LaTeX: .....[LateX code here]....
```

The problem about both of these methods is that they require the LaTeX code really sits on its own line (or lines) separate from "regular org-mode" code/text. But if I want a bullet point followed by LaTeX code, say a  `\url{}`, this doesn't work, as it has to be on the following line:

```
* Heading one
** some point
*** 
#+LaTeX: \url{http://www.gnu.org}
*** something else
*** 
#+begin_latex
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
#+end_latex
```

And, unfortunately, org-mode doesn't seem to be to automatically interpret `\url{}` without LaTeX tags. If I just have:

```
* Heading one
** \url{http://www.hello-world.net}
```

Then the PDF output looks like:

```
* Heading one
** [[http://www.hello-world.net][http://www.hello-world.net]]
```

So, is there a better way to handle LaTeX snippets generally? And, more specifically, some good way of getting URLs to be processed in some reasonable way? (Reasonable here means that they standout in some way (colour or fontface) and are "clickable".)

Edit: The first suggestion in mvarela's answer is, I think, close to what I want, as it actually "looks like a url" in the output. The other possibility suggested here, as well as Seamus's suggestion, are indeed clickable urls in the pdf output, but are formatted as regular text.

Thus:

```
*** \murl{http}{www.google.com}
*** [[http://www.google.com][google.com]]
*** http://www.google.com
*** <http://google.com>
```

Outputs as:

[org output http://gobblin.se/media/media_entries/660/shot-2012-08-09_10-35-36.jpg](http://gobblin.se/media/media_entries/660/shot-2012-08-09_10-35-36.jpg)

Only the first one is visually differentiated from other text.

Comment: Can't you just use <www.whatever.com> or does org mode not support that? Check whether orgmode has a native syntax for explicit urls...

Answer (score 6):

This is hackish, but it does the job:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \newcommand{\murl}[2]{\url{#1://#2}}
\murl{http}{www.google.com}
```

You can also just use the org format for URLs in the `.org` file, which will then be translated into proper TeX:

```
  [[http://www.google.com][google.com]]
```

You can insert such a link with <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd>, if you don't feel like typing it.

Comment: See edited answer above.